# Import and read text file in Swift

Tags: swift, text, import

I tried all the different approaches posted here, and got various errors on each:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100773/load-text-file-into-an-array-in-swift
(Are these up-to-date?)

Most recently, I tried:

```
    func linesFromResourceForced(fileName: String) -> [String] {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)!
    let content = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}

let lines = linesFromResourceForced("file.txt")
print (lines)
```

And got these errors:
"let lines = " --> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'ViewController'
print(lines) --> Expected declaration

What am I doing wrong?
I would also appreciate any other recommendations for the simplest way to import and read text. Thanks!

Comment: Your let and print statements need to be inside a function declaration. Just sitting in a class by itself, print will never be called, so the complier doesn't like it.

Comment: Is this in a Playground?

Comment: What does your full class look like?  You can't just put random lines of code outside of methods.

Comment: Hey @user89326 did my answer help?  Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift 4+

```
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myfile.txt", ofType: nil)!
            let myStringText = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to load the lines from the text file in an iOS app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let lines = linesFromResourceForced("file.txt")
        print (lines)
    }

    func linesFromResourceForced(fileName: String) -> [String] {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)!
        let content = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    }
}
```

You need to declare the function in your class, and call it in the context of another function.  So when your view controller loads, `viewDidLoad`, it will call `linesFromResourceForced` to load up your array of lines and print them in that context.